# Office 365 User Profile Custom Property Retrieve problem

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365-develop-tool

I have created some custom property for user profile. All users are able to see and edit those fields value from edit profile page. After creating all custom fields total property become 122. When i try to read all the users from "User Information List" it return all users with only 73 properties my custom fields are not available there.

I need to read all the user profiles I am not sure "User Information List" is the right place or not to get all users.

My questions are

1. Which is the right list to get all the user profile from office 365.
2. How can i get all the custom field and filter on it.

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish this you need to mark the created profile properties as replicateable. Then those properties are available on site collection level too.
If the property for example is marked as private then the property won't be replicated at all.

You will find more information about property replication in the [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262930%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

I think this work the same way in Office 365 too.

Answer (score 1):

The User Info list is the wrong place to look. Instead you need to query the User Profile web service.  You can find the details on using it [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163800.aspx)